# Touch not recognized ever in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to convert my pong game from keyboard usage to touch based mechanics. However I am completely stuck trying to figure out Unity's touch mechanics. I have searched through the internet and everyone somehow keeps resolving the issue in ways that are still failing for me. Here is, from everything I have gathered, what I believe should work. This is in my update method so it is constantly checking this.

```
    Touch t;

void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        print("touch seen");
        t = Input.GetTouch(0);
    }
}
```

The if statement condition is never met no matter how many times I touch the screen. I am using a lenovo laptop that has a touch screen, maybe it is reading my touches as clicks? I just can't seem to figure it out. If I take away the if statement I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. Any help is extremely appreciated!

**Update** It is registering as a mouse click, and I can't just allow this because I need multiple touch inputs.

Comment: Giving a mouse input version a quick try should answer your question regarding this. (I think computer touch screens actually handle it as mouse clicks.)

Comment: It did register as a click, but then how do I debug the program? @GunnarB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Input.touchSupported` to check if touch is supported on your computer. If it returns `true`, then read from touch with `Input.GetTouch(0)`. If it returns `false`, then use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` to read from the mouse instead. *Touch won't work if your computer does not support touch screen*. Below is complete code on how to do this:

```
void Update()
{
 if (Input.touchSupported)
 {
    Debug.Log("TOUCH IS SUPPORTED");
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
    {
        print("touched screen");
    }
 }
 else
 {
    Debug.Log("TOUCH IS NOT SUPPORTED");
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        print("clicked screen");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It says it isn't supported, how do I make it support it because I know my computer has touch. I was able to easily program touch in LibGdx Java

Comment: @Luke If it is not supported, then it wont work. What Leno model number and what Os version?

Comment: Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15, Windows 10

Comment: @Luke Just did some research about this problem. Before I make a statement, what Unity version are you using?